# Rotating a polygon around the origin (its center)

Tags: python, pyqt5, rotational-matrices

I'm trying to rotate a polygon around its center. To make things easy, I positioned it in the origin of the canvas so that I don't have to translate it back and forth. This is the rotation function I came up with:

```
        """
        rotates robot's vertices around its center point
        """
        # configure angle parameters
        angle = np.deg2rad(phi)

        rotated_vertices = []
        for vertex in vertices:
            # translate points to the origin
            x_new = vertex[0]
            y_new = vertex[1]

            x_new = x_new*np.cos(angle) - y_new*np.sin(angle)
            y_new = x_new*np.sin(angle) + y_new*np.cos(angle)

            rotated_vertices.append([x_new, y_new])

        return rotated_vertices
```

This applies a simple rotation to each vertex (x, y) in a set of vertices that make up the polygon. As I start to increase the angle of rotation, the shape begin to get distorted until it ends up being a line. I have the samples below:

Rotations angle = 0
[image]
Rotation angle = 50
[image]
Rotation angle = 70
[image]

Thank you in advance. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong

Comment: are you trying to make it rotate in 3d space? or just spin in a circle?

Comment: The formulas you have here look fine so it's likely something else.

Comment: The question is unclear, especially since you've tagged it for pyqt5, so you may be using a QPainter device or even a QGraphicsScene that would apply its own transform matrices. Please [edit] and improve your question so that we have a better context of what you're trying to do, possibly while providing a valid [mre].

Comment: Look carefully at that matrix multiplication. What X value *should* it be using when computing `y_new`?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you update the xnew first then use the rotated xnew to compute ynew, and that's where it goes wrong.

```
        x_new = x_new*np.cos(angle) - y_new*np.sin(angle)
        y_new = x_new*np.sin(angle) + y_new*np.cos(angle)
```

Instead, do something like

```
            x_rotated = x*np.cos(angle) - y*np.sin(angle)
            y_rotated = x*np.sin(angle) + y*np.cos(angle)
```

Also, a few points here: you are already using numpy, so why don't you just define a rotation matrix and and use numpy's matmul? That would usually avoid time waste on such error:

```
import numpy as np
phi = 45
vertices = [(-5, -5), (-5, 5), (0, 6), (5, 5), (5, -5), (0, -6)]
angle = np.deg2rad(phi)

def get_rotate_2d(rad):
    return np.asarray([[np.cos(rad), -np.sin(rad)],
                       [np.sin(rad), np.cos(rad)],
                       ])


vertices_numpy = np.asarray(vertices)
rot_mat = get_rotate_2d(angle)
rotated_vertices = (rot_mat@vertices_numpy.T).T
```

Also, for any abstraction of the geometric operation, I would suggest [shapely](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html). For your problem here, with `shapely` you only need a few lines to utilize its affine transformation

```
import shapely
from shapely.affinity import rotate
vertices = [(-5, -5), (-5, 5), (0, 6), (5, 5), (5, -5), (0, -6)]
p0 = shapely.Polygon(vertices)
phi = 45
p_ratated = rotate(p0, angle=phi, origin='center')
```

Answer (score 0):

Your formulas are fine.

The problem comes from the usage of `x_new` and `y_new` on them, specially for the calculation of `y_new` which is using the rotated value of `x` and not the original one.

Try this instead:

```py
x_new = vertex[0] * cos(angle) - vertex[1] * sin(angle)
y_new = vertex[0] * sin(angle) + vertex[1] * cos(angle)
```